# Is it technically correct to say "Don't blow up the balloon too much as it will pop" or "Don't blow the balloon too hard as it will pop"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I searched Google Books for "**blow up the balloon too much**" and "**blow up the balloon too hard**" and both suggest the balloon  will pop.

Is there any difference between the two?

**Or which one is more technically correct?**

Comment: I would say "Don't **blow up** the balloon too much or it will burst."

Comment: What technical manual are you asking us to consult?

Comment: @ColinFine, ???

Comment: Well, as far as I'm concerned, _technically correct_ is a meaningless phrase in this context, because there is no such thing as a technical standard for English. So I was inviting you to identify the standard against which you wished us to evaluate the phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things at play here.

First, as Kate notes, "blow up" is an alternative to simply "blow", and, like her, I would tend to say the former. Or, I might say "inflate". In this context, "blow up" and "inflate" both refer to directing air *into* the balloon, whereas "blow" could also mean directing the air *at* the (already inflated) balloon.

Then, "too much" and "too hard" have slightly different connotations. "Too much" would tend to refer to the *volume* of air used to inflate, whereas "too hard" would be more likely to refer to how *quickly* that volume was introduced into the balloon.

Since I suspect that what would cause a balloon to rupture is introducing too much air, not introducing it too quickly, I think you want "too much". Again, as Kate said, better to have "blow up" than just "blow". Finally, I also prefer her "burst" to the original "pop", but that might just be a geographical thing.